# sql update column from another column in the same table in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

UPDATE table1 SET column1 = column2 WHERE column3 = 'abc';

How do I execute the above query in sql alchemy ORM

```
table1 = Table('table1', metadata,
    Column("column1",     SmallInteger(),     nullable=False, autoincrement=False),
    Column("column2",     SmallInteger(),    nullable=False, autoincrement=False),
    Column("column3",     String(length=255), nullable=False)
)

class Table1(object):
    pass
mapper(Table1, table1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DBSession.query(table1).filter_by(column3 = 'abc').update({"column1":column2}, synchronize_session=False)
```

use this

```
where  ==== filter_by
table1 === class containing the table1 schema
update command with columns as key in query
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html follow this link will guide you

Comment: I get this error 
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'self_group'